# How can i filter out an item by its id?

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-props

This function is meant to delete the todo items but i don't really understand what it does, like why do you filter out the todo that doesn't have the same id with the id that is passed in the function...can anybody help me to explain? Thank you so much!

```
const handleDelete = ({id}) => (   setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id))
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array like this todos=[item1, item2, item3]. You click on the item1 in order to remove. So you filter the todos array, and get back all the items that are not item1. Now you have [item2, item3] in your todos array.

Answer (score 0):

The filter() method returns a new array with all the elements that pass the test. So, in your case, you pass an array with all todos except the one with the given ID to the setTodos() function. So, the todo with the specified id has been ‘removed’.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter for more info about Array.prototype.filter()

Answer (score 0):

React uses shallow reference equality checks as part of its Reconciliation process in order to determine what has updated in state/props and what needs to be flushed out to the DOM.

[Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

React uses [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) for the shallow equality checks.

> `Object.is()` determines whether two values are the same value. Two
> values are the same if one of the following holds:
>
> - both `undefined`
> - both `null`
> - both `true` or both `false`
> - both strings of the same length with the same characters in the same order
> - both the same object (meaning both values reference the same object in memory)
> - both numbers and
>
>   - both +0
>   - both -0
>   - both NaN
>   - or both non-zero and both not NaN and both have the same value
>
> This is *not* the same as being equal according to the `==` operator. The
> `==` operator applies various coercions to both sides (if they are not the same Type) before testing for equality (resulting in such behavior
> as `"" == false` being `true`), but `Object.is` doesn't coerce either value.
>
> This is also not the same as being equal according to the `===`
> operator. The only difference between `Object.is()` and `===` is in their
> treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs. For example, the `===` operator
> (and the `==` operator) treats the number values `-0` and `+0` as equal.
> Also, the `===` operator treats `Number.NaN` and `NaN` as not equal.

```
const handleDelete = ({ id }) => {
  setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
};
```

The reason for using `Array.prototype.filter` to remove an element from an array stored in React state is ***because*** it returns a ***new*** array reference. This is what allows React to "see" that the array has been updated and needs to be rerendered.

We want to return all elements ***except*** the one the matches by `id` into a new array.

I suggest also when updating arrays to *always* use a functional state update so you ensure you are updating correctly from the previous state, ***since removing an element from the array necessarily depends on the previous state***. It's a trivial change to effect this improved behavior.

```
const handleDelete = ({ id }) => {
  setTodos(todos => todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering in React is the process of looping through an array and including/excluding elements inside that array based on a condition that we provide. `filter` returns a new array once the iterations are complete. You need to assign that filtered array to a new variable. Since filter doesn't mutate the original state array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you change your function like the following piece of code it will work as you want:

```
const handleDelete = ({id}) => (  
  this.todos = this.todos.filter((t) => t.id !== id)
)
```

At least this might work at vue, just try it out if this also works and react maybe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).